# how do I use web deploy to deploy multiple sites on localhost with different ports

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a solution that contains multiple integration test projects and one web application project. each integration project connects to the web application when running the tests. I would like for each test project to access the website with its own database connection. I have been trying to use the web deploy functionality built into visual studio. However I have been unable to figure out what I need to add to either the deployment package that is created and/or the post build event for the test projects to declare the binding port for the website when deployed. For example, I want integration project A to create and access the website located at http://localhost:83 and integration project B to create and access the website located at http://localhost:82. Could someone please explain:

1. Is there anything I need to do the deployment package ?
2. What do I need to add to my post-build events for my integration projects when deploying the package, so that the website is created at the correct port when building the project?

Update:
I'm wanting to deploy the same site to two different locations on my machine so that I can run both sets of integration tests at the same time.

Update 2:
I have researched the web deploy tool and it allows you to specify parameters that modify what is deployed when you call it from the command line. However I have found the documentation very confusing. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568968(WS.10).aspx

Update 3:
I expect these to be two different websites, each pointing to there own database. If possible I would like a single package that can be deployed using msdeploy. Which will then be called in a post build event from each of the integration test projects. I would like to specify the connection string and deployment location from the post build script of the integration project.

Comment: Do you actually intend to deploy these apps to another server later (which is what WebDeploy is really there for) or is this really just about debugging them on localhost (in which case WebDeploy is probably not the right tool to look at). In any case, port bindings are defined on the site level and not per application which is why you're experiencing those difficulties in the first place. But if you could clarify your scenario, please, there might be something that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with webdev.server included in visual studio. VisualStudio use this for start a webserver when you debug. With this you can start a webserver in the desire port (if the port is not used currently).
I made a bat file for change some options.
check it.

::Begin of bat file

cd C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\
WebDev.WebServer40.exe /port:80 /path:"C:\PATHTOYOURWEBPROJECT" /vpath:"/NAMEOFYOURWEBPROJECT"

::End of bat file

You can acces in: http://localhost:80

I use the webserver40, but if you don't have net.4 or vs2010 you can try to find webserver[ xx version].exe

I hope that this will be helpful, and sorry for my broken english.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're approaching this the wrong way.

> *> I would like for each test project to access the website with its
>   own database connection.*

Who is creating the DB connection? Your web site or the test project? For rest of your question to make sense, I presume its the web site (otherwise, Project A and Project B cannot share a connection out of the box).

If your website is making the connection, unless you're *caching* or having a *static connection*, there will be a new connection made as each request runs your your site on a new thread. Another simpler alternative is to take a query param and initiate a new connection based on that. If you seed it off the caller, you can also use it for more detailed logging.

Web Deployment projects are meant for deploying to integration servers, so that means you cannot access them by `http://localhost...` but the full FQDN of the server.

Most importantly, `http://localhost:82/myApp` and `http://localhost:83/myApp` are two different sites (unless you redirect from one of them to another one which in itself can cause additional issues) running the same codebase.

Having said that, you would then need to deploy your website twice and then all you need is to change the config/settings entry in Project A and B to point to these to different sites.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

You can define virtual host configuration.
Refer this guide for more information.

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch07.html

Comment: this is about using the web deploy feature in visual studio. its not even related to java